Campy (Japanese?) Film About an Island of Beautiful Women and Pirates
I recall seeing a movie some years back called "Isle of the Babes" or the like, but cannot for the life of me find it. A rough synopsis is as follows:

An island full of beautiful women is happened upon by a group of pirates. Some of their members are captured by a tribe of women who take them hostage and use them for 'breeding'. One of the women in this tribe falls in love with one of the pirates and somehow they escape.

Very rough synopsis, but the key themese are: island full of beautiful women, asian cinema, camp adventure comedy. Oh, and pirates. I would say it was mid to late 70's, colour. It wasn't especially 'adult', I'd describe it as an action/adventure/comedy film, but I think the 'comedy' was more an intrinsic part of the premise rather than the screenplay or dialog. 
Does anyone out there have any idea what this film could be?

So, are you looking for the movie "Isle of Babes"?

Hi. Do you remember the approximate year\decade of release? The tone (comedy? thriller? action?) [@steelerfan I dread to even google that. ;)]

@steelerfan Well I believe that's what it was called, but Googling it turns up zilch.

@Walt I would say it was mid to late 70's, colour. It wasn't especially 'adult', I'd describe it as an action/adventure/comedy film, but I think the 'comedy' was more an intrinsic part of the premise rather than the screenplay or dialog.

Sounds like the exact plot of the Taiwanese adventure movie Warrior Women (AKA Island Warriors AKA The Country of Beauties) from 1981.

Semi-naked Amazonian warriors defend their girls-only island from from male pirates from the men-only island. Men are only free to roam the island if they are wearing chastity belts and if they remove their belts they get castrated. It's all-out war when the men try abolish the women only baby rule.

Couldn't find clips (it's a bit obscure) but here's the DVD art (the poster that's on IMDb hilariously has nothing to do with the movie) and you can find some more pics here and here. Here are the ladies:


Wow, yep that's it! I literally (and I mean that in the proper sense of the world), saw this at midnight on a community television channel when I was 10 years old. That DVD cover is exceptional. Bravo!
